# Third column div not getting positioned correctly

Tags: css, html

I don't know if it would be hard to explain but here it goes.. I have a number of divs on my page and I want them to come in a column layout. The page has a nav bar, a logo, some profile data and 3 more divs. Those 3 divs are not getting aligned correctly. The first one is floated left and the second one is just after that and so is also floated. I want the third to be floated right but in alignment with the first two.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59ENh/).

I want `.commitment_box` div to be floated right in alignment with those `.major_data`.

**CSS:**

```
.major_data {
    margin: 110px auto;
    width: 40%;
}
.major_data .profile_box p:first-child {
    border-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #eee;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.major_data .profile_box p:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: justify;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.major_data .profile_box p {
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
}
.commitment_box { /*the div i want to be floated right in alignment with those about boxes */
    margin-top: -58.2%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 25%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    float:left;
}
.commitment_box .commitment p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 1.5%;
}
.commitment_box .commitment p:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="commitment_box">
    <!--/*the div i want to be floated right in alignment with those about boxes */-->
    <div class="commitment">
        <p>Alex:</p>
        <p>He's works great.aidhoaishdoaishdoaishdoaishdoaihdoaishdoaishdoasihdoasidhoasihd</p>
    </div>
    <div class="commitment">
        <p>Alex 1:</p>
        <p>He's works great.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="commitment">
        <p>Alex 2:</p>
        <p>He's works great.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="commitment">
        <p>Alex 3:</p>
        <p>He's works great.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="commitment">
        <p>Alex 4:</p>
        <p>He's works great.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So basically, you want a 3-column layout?

Comment: You are setting the position of element by using margin. I.E .major_data {
    margin: 110px auto;
    width: 40%;} I don't think it is good solution. Try to find somewhere 3 column layout and learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid **float**. It is not a very good coding style.

Make big sections as **`inline-block`** elements and give them, for example, **`width: 30%`**

Here is a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aKa6W/)** with the styles that are simplified so that you would see the important changes

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a float:left on the .major_data box too, and put the same top margin on both boxes.